# i'm facing a error is Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

my schema file is here

```
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

export const memberAddressSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  mumber_id: { type: String, required: true },
  city_id: { type: String, required: true },
  state_id: { type: String, required: true },
  pincode: { type: String, required: true },
  address: { type: String, required: true },
});
```

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tree')

````
@Module({
    imports:[MongooseModule.forFeature([{name:'Admin', schema:adminSchema},{name:'Member',schema:memberAddressSchema}])],
    providers:[AdminService,MemberAddressService],
    
    exports:[AdminService,MemberAddressService]
})
export class AdminModule{}```
````

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using the `memberAddressSchema`?

Comment: i'm attach the file in the edit section in the bottom

Comment: can you show us the stack trace?

Comment: i'm not understand ???

Comment: I've never seen the import done as `import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
` is that functionally the same as `const mongoose = require('mongoose');`?

Comment: actually this functionally *means you used the mongoose package on the directory every where you used mongoose on the given directory

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I mistakenly added schema to `imports` array of the `@Module`. I removed it and it fixed the problem.